# Error: columnListA[i] is undefined

Tags: javascript, json, splice

When i try to delete some object from columnListA with the objects present in columnListB i'm getting `Error: columnListA[i] is undefined`

can anyone please tell me some solution for this.

my json list is shown below:

```
columnListA =[ {id:"a1", value:"XYZ"},{id:"a2", value:"ABC"},{id:"a3", value:"JHI"},{id:"a4", value:"PLM"}]

columnListB =[ {id:"a1", value:"XYZ"}]
```

My code is this

```
for ( var j = 0, selLength = columnListB.length; j < selLength; j++)
{
    for ( var i = 0, nonSelLength = columnListA.length; i < nonSelLength; i++)
    {
     if (columnListA[i].id=== columnListB[j].id)
     {
       columnListA.splice(i, 1);
     }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
for ( var j = 0; j < columnListB.length; j++)
{
    for ( var i = 0; i < columnListA.length; i++)
    {
        if (columnListA[i].id === columnListB[j].id)
        {
            columnListA.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tWnN2/)

Remove `nonSelLength = columnListA.length; i < nonSelLength;` from loops and just define variable as less than length of the object

Answer (score 2):

You're getting this because you're changing `columnListA` inplace. Since you delete an element, its length passes from 4 to 3, but you still iterate until `i` = 3.

I suggest creating a new array, instead of changing it inplace and risking this type of error. Example:

```
columnListA = columnListA.filter(function(nonSel) {
  return columnListB.some(function(sel) {
    return sel.id !== nonSel.id;
  });
});
```

[`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) takes a function, and returns a new array that contains only the elements for which the function returns true.

[`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) takes a function, and returns `true` if the function returns true for all the elements on the array, and `false` otherwise.

Comment: I don't think it is faster, but I find extremely unlikely that the difference will be noticeable unless you're talking about hundreds of thousands of items. Optimize for legibility and ease of maintenance, and look for performance **only** if it isn't good enough